# Horizontal scrolling collection view partially hiding first cell content on initial load

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a `UIView` and inside that, I have added a `UILabel` and `UICollectionView`. The `UICollectionView` scrolls horizontally. But the issue is that when I run the app, the `UICollectionView` offset is set in such a way that the first cell is partly hidden. If I scroll to the right then I can see the contents of the first cell. But when I let go it bounces back to its original hidden state.

As you can see here the first cell has 2 `UIViews` but only the second one is visible.

[image: sideways hidden cell layout]
[image: front view of hidden cell]

When I scroll right, this is how it looks:

[image]

The, I... 10, is the cell that is getting hidden. I have added the elements programmatically, so could be a constraint issue. But I can't zero down on what could be causing it.

Here's my `UICollectionViewCell`:

```
class UserCountryCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let countryNameLabel: UILabel
    let countryUserCountLabel: UILabel
    
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        countryNameLabel = UILabel()
        countryUserCountLabel = UILabel()
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.addSubview(countryNameLabel)
        countryNameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        countryNameLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13)
        countryNameLabel.textColor = .white
        
        self.addSubview(countryUserCountLabel)
        countryUserCountLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        countryUserCountLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13)
        countryUserCountLabel.textColor = .white
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            countryNameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 5),
            countryNameLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            countryNameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 5),
            countryNameLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 5),
//            countryNameLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 0),
            countryNameLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),

            countryUserCountLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: countryNameLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 5),
            countryUserCountLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 5),
            countryUserCountLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 5),
            countryUserCountLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -5),
            countryUserCountLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            countryUserCountLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
        ])
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func configureCell(countryName: String, countryUserCount: Int) {
        countryNameLabel.text = countryName
        countryUserCountLabel.text = String(countryUserCount)
    }
}
```

Comment: First, you should add and constrain subviews to the cell's `.contentView`, not to the cell itself. So, try changing your lines that say `self.addSubview(...)` to `self.contentView.addSubview(...)` and `... .constraint(equalTo: self. ...` to `... .constraint(equalTo: self.contentView. ...` and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - couple things...

As I said in my comment, add subviews and constraints to the cell's `.contentView`, not to the cell itself.

You do have a few mistakes in your constraints. You constrained the `countryNameLabel.trailingAnchor` to `self.leadingAnchor` ... that should be `.leadingAnchor` to `.leadingAnchor`.

Your `.bottomAnchor` constants should be negative.

If you want the labels' text to determine their widths, don't assign a `.widthAnchor`.

Try replacing your init with this:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    countryNameLabel = UILabel()
    countryUserCountLabel = UILabel()
    super.init(frame: frame)
    
    contentView.addSubview(countryNameLabel)
    countryNameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    countryNameLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13)
    countryNameLabel.textColor = .white
    
    contentView.addSubview(countryUserCountLabel)
    countryUserCountLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    countryUserCountLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13)
    countryUserCountLabel.textColor = .white
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

        // needs to be .leadingAnchor to .leadingAnchor
        //countryNameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 5),
        countryNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 5),

        countryNameLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
        countryNameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 5),
        countryNameLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5),
        
        // if you want the label width to fit its text
        //  don't set the label's widthAnchor
        //countryNameLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 0),
        //countryNameLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
        
        countryUserCountLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: countryNameLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 5),
        countryUserCountLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 5),
        countryUserCountLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5),
        countryUserCountLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -5),
        countryUserCountLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),

        // if you want the label width to fit its text
        //  don't set the label's widthAnchor
        //countryUserCountLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
    ])

}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for pointing out the wrong constraint and location to place the subviews in. I had tried removing the width constraint for the country name label, but that did not help auto-sizing the cells.  I tried returning CGSize.zero for cell size and set an estimated cell size for the layout of collection view. Maybe I will make another post about it.

Comment: Here's the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65680963/horizontal-scrolling-collection-view-cells-not-resizing-based-on-content-width

Comment: Also, this setup has a strange issue where the collection view shifts up on scrolling: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65681344/horizontal-scrolling-collection-view-shifts-up-when-scrolled-in-parent-container