# Horizontal scrolling collection view cells not resizing based on content width

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have initialized the collection view like this:

```
 override init(frame: CGRect){
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.itemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize
        layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 30)
        
        countryCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        
        viewTitleLabel = UILabel()
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupTableView()
        sortedDummyData = dummyData.sorted(by: <)
    }
```

And I return size as `CGSize.zero`:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
//        return CGSize(width: 70, height: 30)
        return CGSize.zero
    }
```

This is how my cell is defined:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
        countryNameLabel = UILabel()
        countryUserCountLabel = UILabel()
        super.init(frame: frame)

        contentView.addSubview(countryNameLabel)
        countryNameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        countryNameLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13)
        countryNameLabel.textColor = .white
        
        contentView.addSubview(countryUserCountLabel)
        countryUserCountLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        countryUserCountLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13)
        countryUserCountLabel.textColor = .white
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            countryNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 5),
            countryNameLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            countryNameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 5),
            countryNameLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -5),
//            countryNameLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 0),
//            countryNameLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),

            countryUserCountLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: countryNameLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 5),
            countryUserCountLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 5),
            countryUserCountLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -5),
            countryUserCountLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -5),
            countryUserCountLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            countryUserCountLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
        ])
    }
```

This is the output I get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This update worked for me:

Returning non-zero cell size:

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 70, height: 30)
//        return CGSize.zero
    }
```

Updated cell constraints:

```
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            countryNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 5),
            countryNameLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            countryNameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 5),
            countryNameLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -5),
//            countryNameLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 0),
//            countryNameLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),

            countryUserCountLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: countryNameLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 5),
            countryUserCountLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 5),
            countryUserCountLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -5),
            countryUserCountLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -5),
            countryUserCountLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),

// Removed the width constraint
//            countryUserCountLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
        ])
```

[image]